# How can I disable redis cluster replication

Tags: redis, failover, redis-cluster

We have an application here which uses redis cluster to hold some short lived keys, on the order of 2 seconds.  While we want the master to fail over to the slave if something happens to the master, short term loss of this ephemeral data is unimportant.  To save bandwidth we'd like to disable replication between the master and slave.  Is there any configuration that of master and slave in a cluster that can make this happen?

Comment: Is it actually a cluster or is it just master-slave replication?

Comment: It's actually a cluster.  Not just a `slaveof` situation